# How to capture windows Image for deployment

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop

I would like to capture Windows 10 installation. Basically I have Windows installed on my laptop. The installation is ideal. It is activate, has office, Photoshop, chrome, ... installed. I want to know if I could generate an ISO file from my installation so that every time I install the new ISO, all my favorite application will be automatically installed. I have done some research on how it works, but still don't get it completely. In this [tuto](https://askme4tech.com/sysprep-and-capture-windows-10-dism), there are good explanations. I followed it but I don't know how to get the ISO file.

Answer (score 1):

You are ling of crossing a lot of different issues here. You use the phrase "for deployment" and I am not sure if that is what you mean. As a rule "for deployment" means dropping that image on multiple different computers. From that standpoint, at the least,  you will have a million licensing issues and unless the computers are 100% identical you will have driver issues.

I took your question more to mean that on occasion you would want to drop this image back on the same computer whenever the computers gets bloated or corrupt. In that case you can use one of a million imaging programs. Clonezilla is a good one. You make an "image" of the hard drive to say a eternal USB hard drive then when the time comes you can drop that image back on your computer and it will be right back to the point you made the mage.

You really need to let us know what you are trying to accomplish.....